# using openssl in my windows and mac share library

Tags: c++

I am writing both a software to have windows and mac version. The program need ssl socket communication. How I can create a openssl shared library between mac and windows. And make the program can run in a machine which doesn't have openssl install on it

Answer (score 1):

You need to compile openssl library both on Mac and Windows, and link the static library (.lib for Windows and .a for Mac) into your executable respectively.

Comment: that's what I think also. But I don't know how to create a static library

Comment: Download source code of openssl, and follow the instructions in the documents of openssl, it is not hard